# Javascript Image not display on the site

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to display image using javascript but the image is not displaying. I have used ajax to get data and then append the value of the image to a URL before display the image. after appending the image to URL I check the console, I can see that the URL of the image is correct which is pointing to the image. I can even copy the URL from the console and paste it on the browser and the image display well. However, the image is not displaying when i append the url to img2.appendChild(image);

```js
const URL="http://test/somtest?random=random";
const url="Http://test/document/img/";

function getdata() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let img2 = document.getElementById("image");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.src=url+data.image;
          console.log(image);
           
     while (img2.firstChild) {
                     img2.removeChild(img2.firstChild);
                 }
   img2.appendChild(image);    
            
        }
 }

       xhr.open('GET', URL);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Images can't have child nodes, try this instead:

```
const URL="http://test/somtest?random=random";
const url="Http://test/document/img/";

function getdata() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let img2 = document.getElementById("image");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            img2.src=url+data.image;
        }
    }

       xhr.open('GET', URL);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

BTW, if you are using modern browsers (not IE) check the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Comment: I try that it still not displaying the image

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding the image properties, the hight, and the width

```js
const URL="http://test/somtest?random=random";
const url="Http://test/document/img/";

function getdata() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let img2 = document.getElementById("image");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            image.src=url+data.image;
            image.height = 100;
            image.width = 100;
            img2.appendChild(image);

        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', URL);
    xhr.send();
}
```